# Linking with OpenSSL, libcurl, and zlb in AWS CPP SDK

Tags: aws-sdk-cpp

I am trying to build AWS-CPP SDK on Linux and Windows. It has dependency of OpenSSL, zlib, and libucurl.  Although these packages are available on Linux, they are not on Windows. How do I specify the locations of these packages' header files and libraries?
I also have more recently versions of these packages on Linux.  How do I override the default paths?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any special requirements for Windows. As you can see from this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-cpp/v1/developer-guide/setup.html

Only Linux requires those extra libraries. On Windows, it will use whatever is provided by platform/Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

All 3 dependencies are found for Windows  - both x32 and x64 bit architectures.

You may also build them from source.

1. OpenSSL can be found here (and on other sites too):
   https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries
2. Zlib is found at :
   https://github.com/kiyolee/zlib-win-build
3. libCurl can be built from source too:
   https://curl.se/docs/install.html

Building from source code is necessary, if you want the resulting .LIBs(static)  and/or DLLs, to be compatible with your version of Visual C++/Studio(2005-2022).